# How to send information from GUI to excel spreadsheet? Below is my code

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from openpyxl import *
```

I want to save information into this work book by a user using the GUI I have created.

```
master = Tk()
wb = load_workbook('C:\\Users\\broc\\PycharmProjects\\GLTDB\\gltdb.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

# Excel sheet location
sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "Date"
sheet.cell(row=2, column=1).value = "Production Hour"
sheet.cell(row=3, column=1).value = "Production"
sheet.cell(row=4, column=1).value = "Scrap"
sheet.cell(row=5, column=1).value = "Operators"




# Function to take data from GUI put into Excel


def insert():
    if (date.get() == "" and
        prodhour.get() == "" and
        production.get() == "" and
        scrap.get() == "" and
        operators.get() == ""):

        print("empty input")

    else:

        current_row = sheet.max_row
        current_column = sheet.max_column

        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=1).value = date.get()
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=2).value = prodhour.get()
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=3).value = production.get()
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=4).value = scrap.get()
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=5).value = operators.get()

        wb.save('C:\\Users\\broc\\PycharmProjects\\GLTDB\\gltdb.xlsx')
        date.focus_set()

        clear()

# GUI
master.title("Enter Production results here.")
master.geometry("350x200")
master.config(background='lightblue', borderwidth=5)

# Labels for GUI
date = Label(master, text="Date", bg='lightblue').grid(row=0)
prodhour = Label(master, text="Production Hour", bg='lightblue').grid(row=1)
production = Label(master, text="Production", bg='lightblue').grid(row=2)
scrap = Label(master, text="Scrap", bg='lightblue').grid(row=3)
operators = Label(master, text="Operators", bg='lightblue').grid(row=4)

# Entries for GUI
date = Entry(master).grid(row=0, column=1)
prodhour = Entry(master).grid(row=1, column=1)
production = Entry(master).grid(row=2, column=1)
scrap = Entry(master).grid(row=3, column=1)
operators = Entry(master).grid(row=4, column=1)
```

I know the submit button needs a command but im not sure where to start to make this happen. I want the user to hit submit and the data go to excel sheet, then in the GUI window I would like it to clear contents or close automatically.

```
# Command Buttons
submit = Button(master, text="Submit").grid(row=5, column=1, stick=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Cancel', command=master.quit).grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop()
```

Comment: ***"I know the submit button needs a command"***: Why didn't do so? Read [The Tkinter Button Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)

Comment: `submit = Button(master, text="Submit").grid(row=5, column=1, stick=W, pady=4)` Don't do this. submit will be set to none. Put the .grid on a new line like `submit.grid()`. Same for all of your labels. This will likely explain why the `date.get` calls aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

add a command to call your insert function to the submit button.

```
#modify the submit button
submitBtn = Button(master, text="Submit", command = insert)
submitBtn.grid(row=5, column=1, stick=W, pady=4)
```

next update your names and follow this template (or a similar one) for your variable-label-entry items. as mentioned in the comments to your question calling a grid in the same line as your creation of the instance can cause issues. not so much with labels as those are static (in this case), but the get() method on the entry boxes will return the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute get()".

```
#Entry field initialize variable 
date = StringVar()
# create entry widget and tie it to variable
dateLabel = Label(...)
dateEntry = Entry(master, textvariable = date)
dateLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
dateEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
```

you can add this next part on to your submit function or create a clearEntryBoxes function to call when the insert() function finishes.

```
#to clear entry fields
dateEntry.delete(0,'end')
```

insert command is trying to write in the next row (headers are columns), while your headers are set up as row labels under the # Excel sheet location, it should be this to match your insert functions format... or flip your insert function to match the locations by adding to the columns instead of rows

```
sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "Date"
sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = "Production Hour"
.
.
.
```

or

```
sheet.cell(row=1, column=current_column + 1).value = dateEnt.get()
sheet.cell(row=2, column=current_column + 1).value = prodhourEnt.get()
.
.
.
```